# Autofill of Tag names in Tag Merge adds a space to new tag name and results in incorrect merge

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, tag-merge-utility

When attempting to merge two tags, the autocomplete option results in adding a space at the end of the text box.  This results in creating the new tag with a + on the end of it.  I experienced this in Chrome but didn't have a chance to test it in other browsers.  Manually removing the space from the end of the input resolves the issue as a manual work around.

Comment: Confirmed on recent Firefox, too. This is super annoying if you don't catch it in time, since you can't rename the `+` tag back anymore, as any attempt to do so reinterprets the `+` as `2b` and thus doesn't find the tag anymore. You have to manually rename the tags on the actual questions.

Comment: @ChristianRau - see my work around.  If you manually remove the space after it, it works just fine.  It's two small problems.  One, the auto-complete adds a space in error and then two, the space is misinterpreted.  I was able to fix the mistake by removing the line ending space and got everything working fine, it's just fully manual now.

Comment: I was talking about the case where you actually *merged* them already, though. (Of course you can blame me for not double checking it, though.)

Comment: @ChristianRau yes, I did this and was able to recover just fine.  If you change "MyTag+ " to "MyTag+" then it works as expected to rename MyTag+ to whatever you need it to be.  Then you just have to clean up the synonyms.

Comment: But when did you remove the line ending space then? Where did you do this? There is no other tag renaming feature other than the merge feature? Oh, wait, do you mean editing the tag name in the source edit box of the merge page? I totally didn't consider that, good to know.

Comment: @ChristianRau after the autocomplete, remove the space before you submit.  You can do it manually right in the text box.  It's also possible to do in the url encoding if necessary.